# Google Visualization Abbreviating Column Labels

Tags: javascript

Using the google visualization API, is there a way to have a table with column headers that are abbreviated, but in say a pie chart using the same data set display the full column label?

Here is a snippit of the javascript:

```
    //create the dashboard and table chart
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
    table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'chart_div',
        'view': {'columns': ViewColumns},
        'options': {
            height: 400,
        },
    });
    dashboard.bind(table);

    //bind the data to the table
    baseData = new google.visualization.DataTable(response);
    dashboard.draw(baseData);

//add a column chart bound to the same data
var columnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
    'containerId': 'column_chart_div',
    'options': {
        isStacked: true,
        height: 400,
        width: 800,
    },
});
columnChart.setDataTable(table.getDataTable());
columnChart.draw();
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="dashboard_div">
    <div id="column_chart_div" class="inline"> </div>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I noticed there is a way to specify css classes for the header row (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#configuration-options), so think there is probably a css solution that would limit my cell width.

Comment: Could you post enough of your code so that we can reproduce your problem? I realise you've self-answered, but since your self-answer leaves some of your needs unmet I can't help but feel your problem isn't (fully) resolved. Show us code, and we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
th.google-visualization-table-th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 50px;  
}

th.google-visualization-table-th:hover {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

This would be perfect if I could get the full text to pop up on hover (over top the neighbor column), but I've had no luck with that.